# Display array as list in angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, string, angular-nglist

I have an array in my javascript called "animals":

```
var animals = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "cow"];
```

My html is:

```
<p>{{animals}}</p>
```

Currently it is displaying like so:

```
["dog", "cat", "horse", "cow"]
```

I'd like it to display like so:

```
dog
cat
horse
cow
```

I've looked at the official Angular documentation for the ng-list directive and am still scratching my head. Is there perhaps  another (better) directive for this?

Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use ng-repeat:

```
<p ng-repeat="animal in animals">{{animal}}</p>
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="animal in animals">{{animal}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you; much simpler than what I was contemplating doing. It works now.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Can you mark this as the answer if it solved your problem?